# How do I keep CPU off when charging?

Tags: charging, battery-life, wakelock

When I connect the USB power source, it makes CPU to stay on (even though "Development->Stay awake" is off).

When charging from a weak power source if makes battery to drain even faster than is case of USB power is not connected at all (because of CPU stays on instead of sleeping).

How do I stop external power connectedness affecting CPU sleeping policy?

I'm not talking about screen being on, it's about CPU being awake (unfortunately it is not easy to see if CPU is on or off).

Comment: What do you mean by "CPU stays on"? Are you talking about the screen being on? Or are you using an app to constantly monitor the frequency at which the CPU is running?

Comment: I keep a program that constantly blinks LED when screen is off, so I clearly see when (CPU is on while screen is off). Usually after I press power button to turn off screen, it blinks several times and stops. But when charger is connected it keeps blinking.

Comment: The program: [brightact](http://vi-server.org/pub/brightact) ([source](http://vi-server.org/pub/brightact.c)); usage: `brightact /sys/...led.../brightness 20 100000 400000 /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep`

Comment: I'm looking at the source you provided, and it's written in plain C. I'm not sure it's possible to run such a program in Android. Which device are we talking about (maker, model)? Which OS is it running?

Comment: Most of my programs for Android are currently in C, require root access and interfaces the Linux kernel directly (I'm currently more Linux hacker than Android hacker). I'm running Android 2.3 on Sony-Ericcson Xperia X10.

Comment: Have you checked what happens if you **don't** run your program while charging? Does the battery drain anyway?

Comment: 1. Android should not be too aware of this program, and it does not touch `/sys/power/wake_lock`; 2. Even without the program I notice that when the charger is nominally connected, but not charging (e.g. there's only about 3V instead of 5V), it discharges faster (approximately the same rate as if some app holds CPU wakelock).

Answer (score 0):

Long press on the power off switch while plugged in, next tap on the power off prompt.   When it powers off make sure the charging light remains on.    If light is not on press power on quickly just so that the battery percentage shows in the center, it should blank screen again and the charging light come on and remain on.  You can retest battery charge percent again anytime.  When ready to use  long press on power on/off to on and watch or wait for rebooting to take place.

Comment: If I power off the device while charging, I think it reboots into a charging mode (with CPU on) instead, just not starting usual Android UI.

Comment: I want Android to be in usual sleep mode (as with not plugged in without any wakelocks), but also charging. For example, if I connect very weak (less than 1 watt) charger, it starts draining battery instead of charging, because of charging keeps CPU on and the weak power input is not enough to keep CPU on, so battery is used more (compared to just standby mode).

Comment: I've only seen charging with CPU off when the battery is _really_ low. In this mode it does not even try to power on, does not react to any buttons and does not light up any LEDS (unless there is already some charge in the battery).

Comment: Battery percentage cannot be shown if CPU is really off. And booting  from really off to "can show the battery percentage" is rather long (it requires Linux kernel to boot up). Long pressing the power button to boot Android from scratch (turned off) is different from continuing the boot from charging mode; the latter is even faster.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that some CPU optimisation disables when phone connected to devices that support data transfer (notebook for example (even sleeping), or some solar cells), so i use USB cable that not support data transfer.