# Prevent disable power saving while charging [root]

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

When I plug my phone to solar cell cpu optimisation turns off and the speed of discharge increases severalfold.

How to prevent cpu always on when phone charging?

Phone: Rooted Samsung Galaxy S III GT-I9300 Android: 4.3

same question:
[How do I keep CPU off when charging?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39302/how-do-i-keep-cpu-off-when-charging)

Comment: Try [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). Trigger:Power connected Action:battery saver on

Comment: Not helps. I think android force disable power saving when connected and return when disconnected. How to disable this behaviour?

Comment: I think Android forces "Power Saving" to keep turned off when the device is charging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that some cpu optimisation disables when phone connected to devices that suport data transfer (netebook for example (even sleeping), or my solar cell), so i use usb cable that not support data transwer.